# for loop looping to tlast item in text file

Tags: php, api

I been working trying everything to get this to work any help would be greatly apreciated.
i tried many couple of ways to get this work but i either get this error that the domain ame parameter is empty or I get the last domain in the txt file.
the txt file is just one domain per line.

```
 $address="file.txt";

  $shit=fopen($address,"r");
 $contents2= fread($shit,filesize($address));


//also tried $domainlist=explode("\n\r",$contents2);
    $domainlist=explode("\n",$contents2);

   for($i=0 ; $i<=count($domainlist); ++$i){
    $domainlist[$i]=$domain;
$contents = file_get_contents("http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?
domainName=$domain&username=$username&password=$password&outputFormat=JSON");


$results=json_decode($contents);


print_r($results);
  unset($domain);
  };

?>
```

Comment: fgets(fileHandle) would read it one line at a time... while($line = fgets($handle)) { // do something }

Answer (score 1):

Easier:

```
$lines = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($lines as $domain) {
    $contents = file_get_contents("http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver  /WhoisService?domainName=$domain&username=$username&password=$password&outputFormat=JSON");
    $results  = json_decode($contents);
    print_r($results);
}
```

You may want to `trim($domain)` or make sure it's valid or other checks before doing `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    $last_line = $line;
}
fclose($file);

echo $last_line;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this...

```
$file = file("file.txt");
foreach($file as $line) {
  // do something with the $line
}
```

I prefer this method unless you're unsure of the file size. If unsure, you may want to consider using `fopen`.